# How to center text vertically in a table cell of column type 'c' or 'p'?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, cell

Here are some tables. We wish to center the text in the table cells vertically. How to write such code?

Table 1:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\label{some table}
\begin{tabularx}{4.9in}{ p{5cm} | c | c | c | c | c | c | c }
\hline
\textbf{Input of Model}  &  \textbf{B@1}  &  \textbf{B@2}  &  \textbf{B@3}  &  \textbf{B@4}  &  \textbf{M}  &  \textbf{R}  &  \textbf{C}  \\  \hline
\textbf{image embedding}  &  $70.3$  &  $52.9$  &  $38.3$  &  $27.5$  &  $24.3$  &  $51.8$  &  $99.5$  \\  \hline
\textbf{detected objects and directly related terms}  &  $63.3$  &  $43.4$  &  $29.1$  &  $20$  &  $19.8$  &  $46.1$  &  $74.3$  \\  \hline


\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Table 2:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\label{some table 2}
\begin{tabularx}{7.4in}{ c | p{1.8cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{3.5cm} | p{3.5cm} | p{3.5cm} }

\hline
\textbf{Image}  &  \textbf{Detected}  &  \textbf{Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Sentences Generated by Model with Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Sentences Generated by Model without Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Standard Model}  \\  \hline
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.8in]{some image}}  &  Winsor chair, deck chair, furnishing, pot  &  item of furniture, upholstered, found in house, chairs  &  0) a dining room with a table and chairs\newline 1) a dining room with a table, chairs and a table\newline 2) a dining room with a table and chairs and a fireplace  &  0) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 1) a dining room with a table and chairs\newline 2) a table with a vase of flowers on it  &  0) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 1) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 2) a table with a vase of flowers on it  \\  \hline



\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `m` type columns are the vertically centered equivalent to `p` type columns. Unrelated: using `center` and `table` will lead to additional white space around the table. It would be better to use the `\centering` command inside the `table` environment. Also, why do you use `tabularx` without using a `X` column?

Comment: Why do you use `tabularx`  since you have no `X` column?

Comment: @Skillmon I have added the necessary code now.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. How to center vertically for "c" column then?

Comment: @piratesailor: Did you try replacing all the `p` columns by `m` columns in your second table? You will notice that the contents of the first column (`c` type)  will automatically be vertically centered.

Comment: @leandriis I have tried by replacing all p with m according what you said. But the first column of images are still not centered vertically.

Comment: @piratesailor, do you see my answer? does it result are close to what you like to achieve?

Comment: @leandriis I tried your code. First, use \linewidth seems to cause the first column to be too wide. Second, it still not force the cells to be centered vertically.

Comment: @piratesailor: To which of the two examples I showed in my answer are you referring?

Comment: @piratesailor: Could you please also clarify the difference to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435900/134144)  especially regarding your second table with the image in the leftmost column?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second table and [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436043/how-to-center-text-vertically-in-a-table-cell-of-column-type-c-or-p?noredirect=1#comment1093679_436043):

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | m{1.8cm} | m{1.8cm} | m{3.5cm} | m{3.5cm} | m{3.5cm} }
\hline
\textbf{Image}  &  \textbf{Detected}  &  \textbf{Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Sentences Generated by Model with Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Sentences Generated by Model without Indirectly Related}  &  \textbf{Standard Model}  \\  \hline
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.8in]{example-image}}  &  Winsor chair, deck chair, furnishing, pot  &  item of furniture, upholstered, found in house, chairs  &  0) a dining room with a table and chairs\newline 1) a dining room with a table, chairs and a table\newline 2) a dining room with a table and chairs and a fireplace  &  0) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 1) a dining room with a table and chairs\newline 2) a table with a vase of flowers on it  &  0) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 1) a table with a vase of flowers on it\newline 2) a table with a vase of flowers on it  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Nevertheless, I would suggest the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumi]{label={\arabic*.},nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},start=0,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Table caption}

\label{some table 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c  P{1.8cm}  P{2.1cm} X  X  X }
\toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{Image}
& \multirow{2}{*}{Detected}  
& \multirow{2}{*}{Indirectly Related}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sentences Generated by Model} 
& \multirow{2}{*}{Standard Model}  \\  
&&& \emph{with} Indirectly Related  
& \emph{without} Indirectly Related  \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[width=0.8in,valign=t]{example-image}  
&  Winsor chair, deck chair, furnishing, pot  
&  item of furniture, upholstered, found in house, chairs  
&  \begin{tabenumi}
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs
     \item a dining room with a table, chairs and a table
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs and a fireplace  
   \end{tabenumi}
&  \begin{tabenumi}
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it  
   \end{tabenumi}
&  \begin{tabenumi}
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
   \end{tabenumi}  \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Brief summary of the changes:

- Removed vertical lines and replaced `\hline` by the rules from `booktabs`.
- Used `tabularx` and `X` columns to make the table as wide as the textwidth.
- Changed the alignment of text from justified to ragged right in order to avoid huge white spaces between words.
- Removed repetition in column headers of the 4th and 5th column. Removed all bold and added a more subtle italic highlight to the difference between 4th and 5th column.
- Introduced a new enumerate like list for the uase in tables.
- Top aligned all contents in all rows (regarding the image with the help of `valign` from `adjustbox`).
- Vertically centered column headers with the help of `multirow`.
- ...

Comment: +1 for your second table.

Comment: so far i haven't time to finish my answer with second table (also answer not receive any response from op :-( ) ... now i complete it with it, on the similar way as you show in your second example (+1).

Comment: @Zarko: I have seen your answer and I like the usage of `cmidrule`. In fact I was also considering to use it but as I untill now did not know one could use non integer numbers in `multirow` I decided against adding the cmidrule. So thanks for showing me something new about multirow, that allows for so much finetunig thath I always considered to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

probably you looking for the first table something like this:

[image]

**edit (1):**

since you provide mwe after the first version of answer, in the second version is considered your document class, but not the width of the first table.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <--- for vertical centering of "X" cell contents

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{table caption ...}
\label{some table 1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries\raggedright}X | c | c | c | c | c | c | c}
    \hline
Input of Model  & \textbf{B@1}  & \textbf{B@2}  & \textbf{B@3}
                & \textbf{B@4}  & \textbf{M}    & \textbf{R}    & \textbf{C}   \\  \hline
image embedding &  $70.3$       &  $52.9$       &  $38.3$
                &  $27.5$       &  $24.3$       &  $51.8$       &  $99.5$       \\  \hline
detected objects and directly related terms
                &  $63.3$       &  $43.4$       &  $29.1$
                &  $20$         &  $19.8$       &  $46.1$       &  $74.3$       \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{table caption ...}
\label{some table 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright}X *{7}{c}@{}}
    \toprule
Input of Model  &  \textbf{B@1} &  \textbf{B@2} &  \textbf{B@3}
                &  \textbf{B@4} &  \textbf{M}   &  \textbf{R}   &  \textbf{C}   \\
    \midrule
Image embedding &  $70.3$       &  $52.9$       &  $38.3$
                &  $27.5$       &  $24.3$       &  $51.8$       &  $99.5$       \\
    \addlinespace
Detected objects and directly related terms
                &  $63.3$       &  $43.4$       &  $29.1$
                &  $20$         &  $19.8$       &  $46.1$       &  $74.3$       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{table caption ...}
\label{some table 3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright}X *{7}{S[table-format=2.1]}@{}}
    \toprule
Input of Model  &  \textbf{B@1} &  \textbf{B@2} &  \textbf{B@3}
                &  \textbf{B@4} &  \textbf{M}   &  \textbf{R}   &  \textbf{C}   \\
    \midrule
Image embedding &  70.3       &  52.9       &  38.3
                &  27.5       &  24.3       &  51.8       &  99.5       \\
    \addlinespace
Detected objects and directly related terms
                &  63.3       &  43.4       &  29.1
                &  20         &  19.8       &  46.1       &  74.3       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

note:

- code in your mwe is (still) not complete
- you use `tabularx` table environment without any `X` column (this cause ugly looks of table)
- labeling table for referencing without of presence of table caption has no sense
- the first table can be fit in width of one column
- i would prefer the last table example

**edit (2):**

let me complete answer with example of the second table. i would design it similarly to what suggest [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) in the second example in his nice answer, but with small differences (in code indicated by `% <---`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{Table with image ...}
\label{some table 2}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    label={\arabic*.},start=0,
                    before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                    after=\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep} % <---
                     } % <---
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{>{\raggedright}p{2cm}} XXX }
    \toprule
  \multirow{2.4}{=}{Image} % <---
& \multirow{2.4}{=}{Detected} % <---
& \multirow{2.4}{=}{Indirectly Related} % <---
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sentences Generated by Model}
& \multirow{2.4}{=}{Standard Model}         \\  % <---
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
&&& with Indirectly Related
  &  without Indirectly Related             \\
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}} % <---
&  Winsor chair, deck chair, furnishing, pot
&  item of furniture, upholstered, found in house, chairs
&  \begin{enumerate} % <---
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs
     \item a dining room with a table, chairs and a table
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs and a fireplace
   \end{enumerate}
&  \begin{enumerate} % <---
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
     \item a dining room with a table and chairs
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
   \end{enumerate}
&  \begin{enumerate} % <---
     \item a table with a vase of flo\-wers on it
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
     \item a table with a vase of flowers on it
   \end{enumerate}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```